# Dúvidas Spring Boot Web App -> Android

Tags: java, android, web-service, spring-boot, restful

Algumas semanas atrás eu terminei o projeto de um sistema web que faz cruds básicos, eu utilizei Java, Maven, Spring Boot, Hibernate, Bootstrap + Thymeleaf pro frontend, etc... E fiz o deploy para o Heroku utilizando o banco de dados PostgreSQL

Agora estou começando a desenvolver para Android e quero criar um app com uma tela de login e um dashboard, ainda estou elaborando o layout. A questão é: Para android não é nem um pouco recomendado, pelo o que li, acessar um banco de dados externo diretamente. Ou seja, o ideal é criar uma API que faça uma ponte com o banco de dados. Então, eu terei que reescrever toda minha aplicação ou posso simplesmente implementar novos controllers RestFul ou modificar meus controllers para que meu app Android acesse os dados?

OBS: No meu app eu quero que o usuário se autentique, mas no meu web app eu não usei nenhum framework para autenticação, como o Stormpath. Eu vou precisar mudar isso? Pois a ideia é usar o sistema tanto no navegador como pelo aplicativo.

Vou deixar abaixo um trecho de código de um dos Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sac/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User newUser, BindingResult bindingResult, String password, String role, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    // Checks if already exists a user with the provided email, to avoid duplicity.
    User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(newUser.getEmail());

    // Search for the authenticated user
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User userAuthenticated = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

    if (userExists != null && password.length() < 5 && bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "Já existe usuário com este e-mail!");
        return registration(newUser);
    }else
        if (password.length() < 5 || bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return registration(newUser);
        }else
            if (userExists != null || bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                bindingResult
                            .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                                    "Já existe usuário com este e-mail!");              
                return registration(newUser);               
            } else {
                userService.saveUser(newUser, role);
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!");
                modelAndView.addObject("role", roleService.findAllRoles());
                modelAndView.addObject("userName", userAuthenticated.getName() + " (" + userAuthenticated.getEmail() + ")");
                modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/sac/registration");         
            }

    return modelAndView;

}
```

EDIT:

Hoje a autenticação do sistema é feito usando Spring Security. Será necessário mudar toda a forma de autenticação do sistema para que meu Android App possa acessar? Abaixo vou deixar os códigos usados pra autenticação:

SecurityConfiguration.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
/*
 * @author: Cisino Junior
 */

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    http.
        authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/access-denied").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/sac/registration").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/sac/consultarUsuarios").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/sac/index").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPPORT")
            .antMatchers("/sac/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPPORT").anyRequest()                
            //.authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/sac/index")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
       .ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/resources/**","/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/font-awesome/**", "/fonts/**");
} }
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("userService")
```

@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
    /*
     * @author: Cisino Junior
     */

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Role role : userRoles) {
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(roles);
    return grantedAuthorities;
}

private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getActive(), true, true, true, authorities);
}}
```

Comment: Olá, buscando a mesma solução encontrei algumas referências. Seguem os links: .. http://andreybleme.com/2017-04-01/autenticacao-com-jwt-no-spring-boot ... https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL62G310vn6nF3gssjqfCKLpTK2sZJ_a_1 .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nwhp_C_BG6c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal seria ter uma api que tanto seu front quanto seu mobile app pudessem consumir...Mas já que já está tudo escrito, você pode reaproveitar as outras camadas(service, repository e etc) que você já escreveu, mas precisa implementar os endpoints que seu mobile app irá consumir.

Você já está usando um framework que cuida de autenticação, de uma pesquisada em OAuth ou JWT com Spring Boot.

Comment: Entendo, então posso criar os rest controllers pro mobile app consumir, show!!! Mas a questão da autenticação ta meio confusa, eu fiz a autenticação usando a interface UserDetailsService e uso o thymeleaf no front end pra esconder elementos dependendo do tipo de usuário, exemplo: <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" >

Comment: Eu to usando o Spring Security, ele não é o suficiente para que meu app acesse com segurança? Desculpe o incomodo, mas isso ta meio confuso pra mim ainda.

Comment: Acho que o ponto principal que está te confundindo é arquitetura cliente x servidor. 

Tenha em mente que tanto seu mobile app quanto o browser são clientes e a comunicação com seu backend(server) é através de requisições HTTP.

No seu front você consegue usar tags como o sec:authorize devido ao view engine (thymeleaf) que renderiza o html, já no mobile, se for um app nativo, não será possível.

Agora se seu app for um webview, não precisa alterar nada...

Comment: Acho que não me expressei corretamente. Minha maior dúvida é na autenticação pelo mobile app, que será nativo(Em java mesmo, pois no momento não tenho tempo pra me dedicar ao Kotlin)... Então terei que mudar a forma de autenticação do sistema, é isso? Pois do jeito que está hoje um mobile app nativo não irá conseguir acessar? Eu vou editar minha pergunta e deixar trechos das classes de config do sistema para você ver como está sendo feito. Novamente, desculpe o incomodo e obrigado pela sua ajuda Tom!!!

Comment: Exatamente, geralmente é utilizado OAuth ou JWT para autenticação mobile. O processo de autenticação é diferente, você não terá uma sessão aberta para cada usuário logado, você terá um token de autenticação que será enviado pelo mobile app em todas as requisições em endpoints protegidos. 

Você precisa mesmo de um app nativo? Não consegue deixar seu layout responsivo e usar um webview? Caso contrário, acho uma boa ideia reescrever sua aplicação já pensando em uma rest api sendo consumida por diferentes clients (browser, mobile e etc).

Comment: Então, o layout é totalmente responsivo e funciona perfeitamente em smartphones. Eu quero fazer o app nativo pois estou estudando Android e gostaria de usar essa situação como exemplo para estudo e estava com essa dúvida referente a autenticação. O ideal seria realmente reescrever a aplicação, mas isso demandaria muito tempo e eu preciso focar mais no Android agora. Acredito que se eu mudar a autenticação e criar os controllers rest será o suficiente pro app nativo acessar, correto? Mesmo não sendo o ideal rs

Comment: Vai ficar bem confuso, mas deve funcionar...tente implementar, comece por um cadastro de usuário, depois autenticação e etc.

Comment: Vou tentar! Obrigado pela sua ajuda Tom!!!